# How do I serve an Angular project from a sub-directory of public_html?

Tags: angular

I have so far only served finished Angular projects in public_html by running ng build, then copying the output, in my local /dist directory, directly into public_html on my server.

I want to serve an app so it is hidden from the public for a while, in public_html/mysecretdirectory/ so I can navigate to www.example.com/mysecretdirectory and demo my work in progress. When I copy the local /dist into public_html/mysecretdirectory and navigate to that directory on the server, the browser console shows 404 errors:

```
GET http://www.example.com/styles.xxxxx.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
GET http://www.example.com/runtime.xxxxx.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
.
.
```

So, it looks like the compiled output is assuming public_html directory for all files. **How do I specify that the compiled project lives in a sub-directory of public_html on the server?**

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about a shared web server. Not local.

What I do is create a `sub-domain` like `ngx-dev.slashand.com` (currently `ngx-dev` doesn't exist), or designate a folder under `public_html` as my sub-domain folder and then publish there. It is my `*QA* server`. I do that for every language in which I write, example, `pi-dev.slashand.com` for Python. Then I would do `http://ngx-dev.slashand.com`. Sub-domain is the best way to go for me.

If you mean serving locally I also do that with: Github: `tapio/live-server` or `http-server`